# PHP POST request redirects to root/xampp dashboard

Tags: php, redirect, post, authentication, xampp

I have a login page with a form with POST method and no action defined (or action to self). I use some functions to do the login, and when some field of the form is left empty or the login credentials are not valid, I´m being redirected to XAMPP dashboard. Its like as if my else statement is not kicking in. Any idea why?

```
if(ifItIsMethod('post')){

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        login_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }else{
        echo "bla bla";
    }
}
```

I tried else{ header(..)} and nothing happens, it just redirects to dashboard.

I have a test version online where the same happens, its here: http://hotfol.com/cms/login_page.php

Thank you!!

Edit: functions

```
function ifItIsMethod($method=null){

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == strtoupper($method)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function login_user($typed_username, $typed_password){
    global $connection;


$typed_username = escape($typed_username);
$typed_password = escape($typed_password);


$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$typed_username'";
$select_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$select_user_query) {
    die ("query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_user_query);
    $user_id    = escape($row['user_id']);
    $username   = escape($row['username']);
    $password   = escape($row['user_password']);
    $firstname  = escape($row['user_firstname']);
    $lastname   = escape($row['user_lastname']);
    $user_role  = escape($row['user_role']);


    if (password_verify($typed_password, $password)) {

    $_SESSION['username']  = $username;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname']  = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $user_role;
    $_SESSION['user_id']   = $user_id;

    header('Location: admin/index.php');
}else{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in ifItIsMethod function? Is it passing?

Comment: what is written in `login_user` function show us

Comment: thank you, edited in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner if statement is always true, but you cannot login when one is empty. Both username and password are always set, but one of them is empty (still set) and the login_user function receives empty data so it cannot login a user. Use `empty()` - it shows true when there is an ampty string.

Comment: Thank you!
I had also another problem, the path. I have to login forms on different folders, it was also messing up the logic.